# Reopen screen based on title

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I created a screen session using the command:

```
screen -t name
```

Based off this name, is there any way to reopen this session (assuming there are no duplicate names) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any option for that -- other than looking through the process list:

```
screen -r $(pgrep -f '\<SCREEN.* -t name\>')
```

On *BSD something different is needed:

```
screen -r $(pgrep -t- -f '\<screen.* -t name\>')
```

The `-t-` option of `pgrep` directs it to match only processes with no controlling terminal, in this case only the `screen` backend process, not the first attached display (`screen` does change the `argv[0]` of the backend process to `"SCREEN"` everywhere, but on *BSD, changes to the `argv` strings are not mirrored in the process list, the way they are on Linux).

On FreeBSD the `-a` option ('also match ancestors of the calling process') may be also needed. Unfortunately, `pgrep -t-` is not supported on Linux, and `pgrep -a` does something completely different.

So, putting it all in a function:

```
# usage tscreen title [args ...]
tscreen(){
    title=$1; shift
    screen -r $(
      pgrep -f "\\<SCREEN.* -t $title\\>" ||
      pgrep -t- -f "\\<screen.* -t $title\\>" ||
      pgrep -at- -if "\\<screen.* -t $title\\>" ||
      echo "title=$title"
    ) "$@"
}
```

Comment: can you break down the script to explain it.  Where does the name go?

Comment: The name is `name` -- pgrep looks through the process list for a process with argv like `^SCREEN.* -t name$`,  finds a pid, then it looks through the screen sockets inside `~/.screen` (which are of the form pid.tty.host) for one socket that matches, whose basename in turn could be used as an argument to the `-r` option.

Comment: turns out that the `-r` accepts just a pid instead of `pid.tty.host`; please confirm if that works for you, too.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work on macOS.  Not sure if it needs a different approach or not.

Comment: try: `tscreen(){ echo screen -r $(pgrep -at- -if "\\<screen -t $1\\>" || echo "title=$1"); }; tscreen <title>`. remove the `echo` if it prints `screen -t pid`, not `-t title=..`. I assume that macOS is similar to FreeBSD. Notice that  on linux `-t-` doesn't work on linux, and `-a` means something completely different.

Comment: I've updated the answer and hopefully made it bsd-compatible.

Comment: it still doesn't work in macOS not exactly sure why.  `pgrep -at- -f` returns a list of process ids I'm assuming by itself.

Comment: Try also with `-at- -if` (case insensitive). But there's one thing I should've asked from the beginning: it there any special reason not to use the `-S` option to `screen` (set session name) in the first place?

Comment: `pgrep -at- -if` still just returns a list of numbers.

Comment: session name I guess is fine I wasn't sure what that was

Comment: This works on my mac `screen -r $(pgrep -f 'test1')`.  I'm not sure what is the best way to incorporate that into the command above.

Comment: `pgrep -f 'test1'` will match too much (any program which contains `test1` in one of its arguments). But if you can start `screen` yourself, and it's not started with  `-t name` from a script you cannot modify, start it with the `-S name -t name` options instead and then you could attach to it by just `screen -r name` or `screen -x name`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use the session name as an argument on the command line:

```
screen -r SESSIONNAME
```

If you have more than one screen with the same session name, you'll also need to specify the PID, like so:

```
[jenny@sameen ~]$ screen -r test1
There are several suitable screens on:
    23669.test1 (Detached)
    23594.test1 (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
[jenny@sameen ~]$ screen -r 23669.test1
```

This is verified in screen 4.01.00devel on RHEL7 and 4.04.00 on BSD.